# What's the difference between shells and xshells?

Tags: shell, kde

In the KDE menu in the Knoppix live CD, I saw there is a submenu somewhere with the title 'shells' and another with the title 'xshells'.

It sounded to me like they are two separate families of shells.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A shell is a command line application that prompts the user for commands and then executes those commands.

"X Shell" is another word for "terminal emulator". It's a graphical application that allows you to run a command line application inside it and thus allows you to execute command line applications in a graphical environment.

When you select an entry in the Shells menu, the selected shell will be started in your default terminal emulator/xshell. When you select an entry in the XShells menu, your default shell will be started in the selected terminal emulator.

Comment: But why isn't Konsole in the XShells menu?

Comment: @HM I don't know. I would have expected it to be in there to be honest.